# Reading plist file. iOS Programming

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, data-management

I have this code and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. As you can see in the code below I have a plist file called `shifts.plist` which is in my `supporting files` folder. Here is my plist structure.
 [image]

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shifts" ofType:@"plist"];
    dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    cell.textLabel.text = [secondTableInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I would ultimately like to read the `name` entries and populate a `UITableView` with them.
I used `NSLog` to output `dictionary` and I got the following. So the file is there it's just 
the parsing that I'm getting wrong.
[image: NSLog output]
Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Try using code to remove the whitespace and the symbols: { } , = ;

Comment: Two maybe-issues with this code:
1) in your plist `Name` is with a capital N while in `objectForKey:` you use a small n
2) you try to call `objectAtIndex` on the object retrieved from the dictionary. As you already get the string object returned from the dictionary, you should not need to call `objectAtIndex:` anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still returning null.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to call `objectAtIndex:` first, then call `objectForKey:`

eg:

```
[[dictionary objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"]
```

Comment: It just makes the app crash. any other ideas?

Comment: Try `[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Root"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"]`

Answer (score 1):

Main Error:-  root is array and you are taking file into dictionary.So declare a NSArray in .h file and retain,nonatomic its property.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shifts" ofType:@"plist"];

array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSLog(@"First Index Name %@",[[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Name"]);
```

I am sure it will answer your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How will I go about reading more than one name? I guess I have to change the `array objectAtIndex:0` part but not too sure what to. Cheers

Comment: Use indexPath.row in place of 0 you will get the desired result. Feel free to ask any question